# Switching from webbrower to http headers and requests

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

Hello i am working on a auto click program and it is working well apart from it goes slow because im using a web browser to visit the websites.

I heard i can use http request to vist websites ?

Im just using

```
   WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)
```

Is there anyway i can edit that so it does a http request to (url)  rather than get the web browser to go there ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) and [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) Classes if all you need is the data.

Comment: Im getting WebRequest  is no declared

Comment: Add Imports System.Net at the top of your .vb file.

Comment: well im doing   Dim inStream As StreamReader
Dim webRequest As WebRequest
Dim webresponse As WebResponse
webRequest = webRequest.Create(url)
webresponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
inStream = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
   but says (url)  is not a url ....... even when i change (url) to textbox1.text it says its not a url .......

Comment: Dim url As New System.Uri(textbox1.text)

Comment: Now its working but views are going up so maybe its not using the proxys ?? like the web brower did ??

Comment: Not sure I'm completely following.  You might want to ask another question for that one.

Comment: Dim inStream As StreamReader
            Dim webRequest As WebRequest
            Dim webresponse As WebResponse
            Dim url2 As New System.Uri(TextBox1.Text)
            webRequest = webRequest.Create(url2)
            webresponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
            inStream = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
  would that code view a web page which is in side url2  or would  i need to make a response to go with it ?

Comment: That should return the data from the url entered into textbox1.  Any nested pages (like an iframe) would likely have to be handled in a different request.

Comment: Ok i just wanna hit the website. E.g for the program to go to the url in textbox1   don't wanna grab any info about it just wanna go to the website ( but not in a web browser )

Comment: When one "hits" a website they are making the request for the page and the server returns data.  This is exactly what this code does.

Comment: Well i have posted the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434367/htpp-request-in-vb-net-program-frezzing   on another question

Comment: I'll see what I can do about answering that question.  If this answer helped you with this particular question, please mark it as the correct answer.